# File content as regex for grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have file with "exp regex" lines. This file can contain lines with other text. For example:

```
exp [a-zA-Z].*\.sh~$
exp test
tmp too
exp tmp
trololo
```

I need to grep content of this file with `egrep file '^exp ' | sed 's/^exp //'` Result of this is:

```
[a-zA-Z].*\.sh~$
test
tmp
```

But I need this grep results separated by | instead of \n

```
[a-zA-Z].*\.sh~$|test|tmp
```

because I need use this result as another grep regex. For example to print files matched by nested grep:

```
ls | egrep "`egrep file '^exp ' | sed 's/^exp //'\`"
```

after nested grep | sed substitution

```
ls | egrep "[a-zA-Z].*\.sh~$|test|tmp"
```

Or is there better way to export regexs from file and use them for filter files?

Kent: how can I use this in subtitution? I thougth it is:

```
ls | egrep "`awk '/^exp /{sub(/^exp /,"");s=(s?s"|":s) sprintf("%s",$0)}END{print s}' file`"
```

but I am propably wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could save the `grep` and `sed`, and use single process: `awk` one-liner

```
awk '/^exp /{sub(/^exp /,"");s=(s?s"|":s) sprintf("%s",$0)}END{print s}' file
```

test a bit:

```
kent$  on feature at master!? echo "exp [a-zA-Z].*\.sh~$
exp test
tmp too
exp tmp
trololo"|awk '/^exp /{sub(/^exp /,"");s=(s?s"|":s) sprintf("%s",$0)}END{print s}'
[a-zA-Z].*\.sh~$|test|tmp
```

Comment: what does `s=(s?s"|":s)` means ? a ternary operator ? oO

Comment: Great but now i have problem with substitution in ``

    ls | egrep -v "`awk '/^exp /{sub(/^exp /,"");s=(s?s"|":s) sprintf("%s",$0)}END{print s}'`"

    :s) sprintf(%s,bash)}END{print s}' .config´: command not found

Do you know what caused this?

Comment: @sputnick it is a short version of: `if s is not empty{use s itself + "|" } else {use s itself, which is empty.}`

Comment: But how the sprintf can feed "s" variable ? oO

Comment: @user2166702 `ls| grep -v "awk..." ` won't work, try this `ls...|grep -v "$(awk '....')"`

Comment: @sputnick it is string concatenation. `s = (s or s"|") concat sprintf(..)`

Comment: @user2166702 or you could first store the result in a var. e.g. `pat="$(awk.....)"` then use `$pat` in your `ls|grep...`

Comment: I wanted put part of code in code tag to `` apostrofs but they are used to code tag here and i am not experienced with text formating in comments. Look at 4th code block in my original question pls to understand.

Comment: @user2166702 I get what you mean. pls try the solution in my two comments ( with "@yourid" )

Comment: @Kent +1 for your _alka seltzer like_ answers and this `awk` (a bit) obfuscated command

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
grep '^exp ' file.txt | sed 's/^exp //' | paste -sd '|'
```

or even better, no need `grep`, `sed` cad do it natively :

```
sed -n '/^exp/s/^exp //p' file.txt | paste -sd '|'
```

Last but not least, if you are open to [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liners :

```
perl -ne 'push @arr, $1 if /^exp (.*)/;END{print join "|", @arr}' file.txt
```

Comment: I don't get you, I have your sample input and my sample output is the same as your sample output.

Comment: Its an old misunderstood version of my response, thanks to delete your comments if you want to clean the place, thanks. I will do it too